# Хранение "Логики" внутри Scriptable Object, в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Я думаю, что SO не планировалось использовать таким образом, все таки, они в первую очередь для хранения статичных данных, однако, у меня есть огромная любовь делать всё что можно и нельзя при помощи конфигов.

Итак, например, я делаю SO для того чтобы задать, как будет двигаться существо. Я вписываю скорость, и хочу так же добавить "тип" движения (по синусоиде, по прямой, по окружности, и т.д.). Однако, я не могу просто выбрать и поместить в SO, какой то класс, наследуемый от образного MoveType.

Единственное решение, к которому я пришел, это использовать enum-ы, а после, прогонять их в при запуске игры через отдельный скрипт, который выберет нужный класс, создаст объект, и передаст его скрипту движения, чтобы он уже при его помощи рассчитывал перемещение.

Таким образом, если этот вопрос не является изначально бессмысленным по какой либо причине, есть ли лучшие способы добиться такого результата?

Примечание: Так же, думаю, можно использовать рефлексию, однако, это все еще чуть более напоминает костыль, чем хорошее решение. Впрочем, возможно именно этот вариант я буду использовать, при отсутствии лучших.

Comment: So с статикой не связан... никакак... то есть совсем. И enum... для чего? Не понял! Создавать объект в реальном времени, но не рандомно, а по сценарию? Почему сразу их не создать в редакторе? Для чего этот квест? А почему для разного движентя просто не написать разные монобехи?

Comment: Ну, под статикой я скорее имею в виду то что эти данные как вшиты в игру, так в процессе и не меняются.

Comment: К вопросу о целесообразности моего подхода. Мне кажется это более чистым в исполнении, скромная фабрика, которой скармливаешь конфиг, а она благополучно создаёт мне кого и как угодно. Особенно это помогает, в случаях если объекту нужна какая то специфичная инициализация. Разные монотеизм, именно в такой ситуации, написать можно, но не одним движением едины. Сейчас мне это же требуется для реализации особых умений, которым нужно иметь особую логику выполнения

Comment: Я понимаю, что so это шаблон профиля юнита, но такое имеет смысл в рпг играх с множеством данных, статы, скин, лут и тд, что бы было легко клепать юнитов по шаблону. Ты говоришь о разных типах движения и это похоже на аркаду, разные враги с разным поведееием, коих не десятки а пару штук. Можно все в рамках префаба и разного набора компонентов просто сделат,ь не воротя уймы сложной архитектуры, так будет более гибко.

Comment: Я и занимаюсь рпг, движение я привёл как упрощённый пример, просто для того чтобы вопрос был понятнее, но видимо эти вызвал путаницу. В оригинале, это мне было нужно для специфичной логики некоторых способностей, и после нескольких часов поисков, я кажется нашёл вопрос, в котором обсуждалась похожая проблема. Я надеюсь на это, возможно, я уже просто сонный, чтобы отличить полезное от бесполезного. В любом случае, я сейчас оставлю тут ссылку, а к утру видно будет. В любом случае, спасибо за участие!

Comment: В твоей архитектуре добавление нового типа поведееия превращается в квест по редактированию кода в несколькиз местах. Симптом раковой опухали. Да в испекторе нельзя выбрать тип класса, но можно сделать so обработчики создания, которые принимают на вход создаваемого юнита и добавляют то что нужно. Все обработчики наследуются от одного типа и в шаблоне массив обработчиков для создания. Может быть связан не только с движением, а с чем угодно и менять код шаблона при добавлкеии новой фичи не нужно, просто новый обработчик. По сути паттерн Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, вот то что я нашёл. Не думаю, что реально сделать что то лучшее в таком вопросе

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73104567/how-do-i-use-a-script-that-is-in-my-scriptableobject

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).